# generating goo.gl not working on localhost

Tags: php

i am trying to dynamically generate the goo.gl links via function.php ,when a post is created ...but its not getting updating the field with the link created on localhost..and i just cant figure out the issue

```
function newlinks($post_id){
    $permaurl=get_permalink($post_id);  
    $shorturl=make_my_url($permaurl);
    update_post_meta('$post_id','shorturl',$shorturl)

  }
  add_action( 'save_post', 'newlinks' );
    function make_my_url($myurl)
    {

    //got te key from https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/projects
    $key = 'AIzBP0';
    $googer = new GoogleURLAPI($key);

    // Test: Shorten a URL
    $shortDWName = $googer->shorten($myurl);
    return $shortDWName; // returns the short url

    }

    // Declare the class
    class GoogleUrlApi {

        // Constructor
        function GoogleURLAPI($key,$apiURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url') {
            // Keep the API Url
            $this->apiURL = $apiURL.'?key='.$key;
        }

        // Shorten a URL
        function shorten($url) {
            // Send information along
            $response = $this->send($url);
            // Return the result
            return isset($response['id']) ? $response['id'] : false;
        }
    // Send information to Google
        function send($url,$shorten = true) {
            // Create cURL
            $ch = curl_init();
            // If we're shortening a URL...
            if($shorten) {
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$this->apiURL);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode(array("longUrl"=>$url)));
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Content-Type: application/json"));
            }
            else {
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$this->apiURL.'&shortUrl='.$url);
            }
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            // Execute the post
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            // Close the connection
            curl_close($ch);
            // Return the result
            return json_decode($result,true);
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is good. I've created my own API key and tried this and works fine. The problem may be in google console.

Please login to https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=pl#p/urlshortener/v1/ and try to generate short url there. Google should ask you to authorize the key you created before. After that code should work fine.

Comment: the code seems to work online but not on localhost....how do i gt it to work on localhost ...did u test on localhost?

Comment: do i need to make any changes in my php.ini?

Comment: I don't think so . f your allow_url_fopen is On then it should work fine.

Comment: its working on server but not my localhost....there must be something i m missing

Comment: for key did u use browser javascript or something else?